# React Native Navigator - transition and unmount previous scene

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React Native app and using the cross-platform Navigator implementation. In one instance I have a scene, the “Login” route, and when the user successfully logs in I want to push to another scene, the “Home” route.

There are two ways I can do this: `navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([routes.home])` and `navigator.push(routes.home)`. In the first implementation, the login scene will be unmounted, but I don't get the benefit of a scene transition. In the second implementation I get a scene transition, but the login route will not be unmounted, even though I have no need to transition back to it.

Is there a way to implement a “Push and Unmount Previous” transition?

Answer (score 0):

The routeStack is an array of all your scenes. How about when your transition completes you just remove it from the array?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `replace(route)`?

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

Comment: `.replace(route)` does not use transitions.

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation, `navigator.resetTo(route)` proved to be a suitable alternative. Note that this doesn't allow you to reset with a stack of routes.

Comment: I don't get get transitions when using navigator.resetTo. How did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.resetTo(route) will only do transitions if you are reseting from a different index. If you are on your initial route, resetTo wont provide transition. For index > 0, resetTo provides a transition same as pop!